# Get substring from string using culture-sensitive comparison

Tags: c#, .net, string

Is there a way of getting a matched substring from a string using a culture-sensitive equality comparison? For example, under the en-US culture, `æ` and `ae` are considered equal. `"Encyclopædia".IndexOf("aed")` evaluates to `8`, indicating a match; however, is there a way of extracting the matched substring, `æd`, that does not involve iterating over the source string? Note that the lengths of the sought and the matched substrings can differ by several characters.

Comment: What about using a regular expression like `(ae|æ)d`?

Comment: @juharr: Regex would be overkill (and introduce its own set of nuances). I need this to implement very general-purpose functionality, such as a culture-sensitive `String.Replace` extension method.

Comment: Related questions: [How can I perform a culture-sensitive “starts-with” operation from the middle of a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15980310/1149773) (by Jon Skeet), [Length of substring matched by culture-sensitive `String.IndexOf` method](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20480016/1149773).

Comment: For anyone interested, I posted a lengthy blog article about this issue, which discusses the various options for resolving it: [Finding substrings using culture-sensitive comparisons](http://dogmamix.com/cms/blog/FindingSubstrings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this by first calling `IndexOf` to get the starting position of the match, then iteratively attempting to identify its length. I optimized for the hot path of the match having the same length as the specified substring; in that case, only a single comparison is performed.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static void Find(this string source, string substring, StringComparison comparisonType, out int matchIndex, out int matchLength)
    {
        Find(source, substring, 0, source.Length, comparisonType, out matchIndex, out matchLength);
    }

    public static void Find(this string source, string substring, int searchIndex, StringComparison comparisonType, out int matchIndex, out int matchLength)
    {
        Find(source, substring, searchIndex, source.Length - searchIndex, comparisonType, out matchIndex, out matchLength);
    }

    public static void Find(this string source, string substring, int searchIndex, int searchLength, StringComparison comparisonType, out int matchIndex, out int matchLength)
    {
        matchIndex = source.IndexOf(substring, searchIndex, searchLength, comparisonType);
        if (matchIndex == -1)
        {
            matchLength = -1;
            return;
        }

        matchLength = FindMatchLength(source, substring, searchIndex, searchLength, comparisonType, matchIndex);

        // Defensive programming, but should never happen
        if (matchLength == -1)
            matchIndex = -1;
    }

    private static int FindMatchLength(string source, string substring, int searchIndex, int searchLength, StringComparison comparisonType, int matchIndex)
    {
        int matchLengthMaximum = searchLength - (matchIndex - searchIndex);
        int matchLengthInitial = Math.Min(substring.Length, matchLengthMaximum);

        // Hot path: match length is same as substring length.
        if (Compare(source, matchIndex, matchLengthInitial, substring, 0, substring.Length, comparisonType) == 0)
            return matchLengthInitial;

        int matchLengthDecrementing = matchLengthInitial - 1;
        int matchLengthIncrementing = matchLengthInitial + 1;

        while (matchLengthDecrementing >= 0 || matchLengthIncrementing <= matchLengthMaximum)
        {
            if (matchLengthDecrementing >= 0)
            {
                if (Compare(source, matchIndex, matchLengthDecrementing, substring, 0, substring.Length, comparisonType) == 0)
                    return matchLengthDecrementing;

                matchLengthDecrementing--;
            }

            if (matchLengthIncrementing <= matchLengthMaximum)
            {
                if (Compare(source, matchIndex, matchLengthIncrementing, substring, 0, substring.Length, comparisonType) == 0)
                    return matchLengthIncrementing;

                matchLengthIncrementing++;
            }
        }

        // Should never happen
        return -1;
    }

    private static int Compare(string strA, int indexA, int lengthA, string strB, int indexB, int lengthB, StringComparison comparisonType)
    {
        switch (comparisonType)
        {
            case StringComparison.CurrentCulture:
                return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.Compare(strA, indexA, lengthA, strB, indexB, lengthB, CompareOptions.None);

            case StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase:
                return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.Compare(strA, indexA, lengthA, strB, indexB, lengthB, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase);

            case StringComparison.InvariantCulture:
                return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.Compare(strA, indexA, lengthA, strB, indexB, lengthB, CompareOptions.None);

            case StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase:
                return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.Compare(strA, indexA, lengthA, strB, indexB, lengthB, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase);

            case StringComparison.Ordinal:
                return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.Compare(strA, indexA, lengthA, strB, indexB, lengthB, CompareOptions.Ordinal);

            case StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase:
                return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.Compare(strA, indexA, lengthA, strB, indexB, lengthB, CompareOptions.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("The string comparison type passed in is currently not supported.", nameof(comparisonType));
        }
    }
}
```

Sample use:

```
int index, length;
source.Find(remove, StringComparison.CurrentCulture, out index, out length);
string clean = index < 0 ? source : source.Remove(index, length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since .NET 5.0 System.Globalization.CompareInfo has method that returns the matched length:
`int IndexOf(ReadOnlySpan<char> source, ReadOnlySpan<char> value, CompareOptions options, out int matchLength);`
See [CompareInfo.IndexOf Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.compareinfo.indexof?view=net-6.0)